Issue with Rendering Images in Canvas for Matching Game in React
I am working on a matching game in React where users need to connect items from two columns. The left column contains text items, and the right column contains images. However, I'm encountering an issue where the images are not rendering correctly on the canvas; instead, they seem to fetch in a loop, which is causing problems.
Here is a simplified version of my component:
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Box, Button } from "@mui/material";

const nodeRadius = 15;
const defaultPairs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    ltype: "text",
    left: "Apple",
    rtype: "image",
    right: "https://example.com/apple.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ltype: "text",
    left: "Banana",
    rtype: "image",
    right: "https://example.com/banana.png",
  },
  // Add more pairs as needed
];

let answerArray = [];

const findClosestNode = (nodes, point, threshold = nodeRadius) =>
  nodes.find(
    (node) =>
      Math.abs(point.x - node.x) < threshold &&
      Math.abs(point.y - node.y) < threshold
  );

const sameVertical = (p1, p2) => p1 && p2 && p1.x === p2.x;
const equalsNode = (n1, n2) => n1 && n2 && n1.x === n2.x && n1.y === n2.y;
const addEdge = (edges, edge) => {
  const leftNodeConnected = edges.some(([start]) => equalsNode(start, edge[0]));
  const rightNodeConnected = edges.some(([, end]) => equalsNode(end, edge[1]));
  if (leftNodeConnected || rightNodeConnected) {
    return false;
  }
  edges.push(edge);
  return true;
};

const renderCanvas = (canvas, leftArr, rightArr) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = 370;
  ctx.canvas.height = 370;

  const rowHeight = ctx.canvas.height / leftArr.length;
  const margin = nodeRadius * 9.0;
  const nodes = [
    ...leftArr.map((_, i) => ({
      id: _.id,
      type: _.type,
      value: _.left,
      x: margin,
      y: i * rowHeight + rowHeight / 2,
    })),
    ...rightArr.map((_, i) => ({
      id: _.id,
      type: _.type,
      value: _.right,
      x: ctx.canvas.width - margin,
      y: i * rowHeight + rowHeight / 2,
    })),
  ];
  const edges = [];

  let activeNode = null;
  let pointer = null;
  let isDragging = false;
  let animationRequestId = null;

  const getPointerPosition = (e) => {
    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top };
  };

  const onTouchStart = (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    pointer = getPointerPosition(touch);
    activeNode = findClosestNode(nodes, pointer);
    isDragging = true;
    if (!animationRequestId) {
      animationRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  };

  const onTouchMove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pointer = getPointerPosition(e.touches[0]);
  };

  const onTouchEnd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = false;
    const closestNode = findClosestNode(nodes, pointer, nodeRadius * 1.5);
    if (
      activeNode &&
      closestNode &&
      !equalsNode(activeNode, closestNode) &&
      !sameVertical(activeNode, closestNode)
    ) {
      const edge = [activeNode, closestNode].sort((a, b) => a.x - b.x);
      addEdge(edges, edge);
      answerArray.push(edge);
      activeNode = null;
    }
  };

  const animate = () => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    edges.forEach(([start, end]) => {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
      ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
      ctx.stroke();
    });

    nodes.forEach((node) => {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(node.x, node.y, nodeRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = equalsNode(node, activeNode) ? "black" : "darkgrey";
      ctx.fill();

      if (node.type === "text") {
        ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText(node.value, node.x - 70, node.y + 4);
      } else if (node.type === "image") {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = node.value;
        img.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(
            img,
            node.x - nodeRadius,
            node.y - nodeRadius,
            nodeRadius * 2,
            nodeRadius * 2
          );
        };
      }
    });

    if (isDragging || edges.length > 0) {
      animationRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
      animationRequestId = null;
    }
  };

  animationRequestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  return { onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd };
};

const Matching = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const [pairs, setPairs] = useState(defaultPairs);

  const leftArr = useMemo(
    () => pairs.map((pair) => ({ id: pair.id, type: pair.ltype, left: pair.left })).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
    [pairs]
  );

  const rightArr = useMemo(
    () => pairs.map((pair) => ({ id: pair.id, type: pair.rtype, right: pair.right })).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
    [pairs]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd } = renderCanvas(
      canvasRef.current,
      leftArr,
      rightArr
    );

    canvasRef.current.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
    canvasRef.current.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
    canvasRef.current.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);

    return () => {
      canvasRef.current.removeEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
      canvasRef.current.removeEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
      canvasRef.current.removeEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);
    };
  }, [canvasRef, leftArr, rightArr]);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
};

export default Matching;


Issue:

Images in the right column are not rendering correctly. When I try to draw images, they seem to fetch in a loop and cause performance issues.

What I've Tried:

Using the onload event for images to ensure they are drawn only after loading.
Debugging with console logs to check the image source.

Expected Behavior:
-Each image in the right column should render correctly next to the text item it is connected to.
Actual Behavior:

Images are not rendering as expected and are causing a fetch loop.
How can I fix this issue to ensure images render correctly on the canvas?

